# How can I sort out this problem in the column 3? The words are shifted to the top.

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{The results.} 
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|}
\hline
{\bf Groups Name}         & {\bf Variance} & {\bf Standard  Deviation} \\[5ex] \hline
{\bf Subject (Intercept)} & 12.45 & 3.529  \\[2ex] \hline
{\bf Residuals}           & 237.09          & 15.398                      \\[2ex] \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I would set the table differently:

- Only few horizontal lines (looks more professional). Package `booktabs` helps.
- Numbers aligned at the decimal dot, see package `siunitx`.
- Package `caption` fixes the vertical spacing around table captions above the table.
- The multi-line cells are generated via inner `tabulars`, the optional parameter controls the vertical alignment (default: vertically centered, `t` = top, `b` = bottom).
- The second table uses left alignment for the left column and uses indentation for the follow-up lines of a table row. This avoids additional space between the lines, as done in the first table and the reader can easily find the start of the table rows.
- LaTeX2e uses `\bfseries` instead of the deprecated `\bf`. Table cells of `tabular` already contain implicit groups, thus the curly braces around `\bfseries` are not needed.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{The results.}
  \label{my-label}
  \begin{tabular}{cS[table-format=3.2]S[table-format=2.3]}
    \toprule
    \bfseries Groups Name & \bfseries Variance &
    \bfseries
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}Standard\\Deviation\end{tabular} \\
    \midrule
    \bfseries
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}Subject\\(Intercept)\end{tabular} &
    12.45 & 3.529  \\
    \addlinespace
    \bfseries Residuals & 237.09 & 15.398 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=3.2]S[table-format=2.3]}
    \toprule
    \bfseries Groups Name & \bfseries Variance &
    \bfseries
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}Standard\\Deviation\end{tabular} \\
    \midrule
    \bfseries
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Subject\\\hspace*{1em}(Intercept)\end{tabular} &
    12.45 & 3.529  \\
    \bfseries Residuals & 237.09 & 15.398 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you *not* create a lot of extra vertical space via `\\[5ex]` and `\\[2ex]`. Instead, simply reset the parameter `\arraystretch` to something like `1.8`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8}
\centering
\caption{The results.} 
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Groups Name} & \textbf{Variance} & \textbf{Standard  Deviation} \\ \hline
\textbf{Subject (Intercept)} & 12.45 & 3.529  \\ \hline
\textbf{Residuals}    & 237.09   & 15.398  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One more answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array,makecell}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{caption}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\caption{The results.}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}C{3cm}|S[table-format=3.2]|S[table-format=3.2]|}
\hline
Groups Name         & \textbf{Variance} &{\thead{Standard\\Deviation}}  \\  \hline
Subject (Intercept) &  12.45            & 3.529                         \\  \hline
Residuals           & 237.09            & 15.398                        \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

It is partly combination of Mico and egreg answers. With addition of `makecell` package the look up of obtained table is close to OP desired one:

[image]